# Type error using ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, types, arraylist, tokenize

```
package mp1similar;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import EarthquakeRecord.Earthquakerecd;


public class MP1Similar 
{ 

private static ArrayList arrayList  ;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 ArrayList arrayList= null;
    try 
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));

    String line="";
    arrayList =new ArrayList();
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
      //  System.out.println(line);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
          //System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            arrayList.add(st.nextToken());
            //System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException ex)
    {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }
          int j=0;
    Earthquakerecd E[]= new Earthquakerecd[2000];
     for(int i=0;i< arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
        E[j] = new Earthquakerecd();


       E[j].setDate(arrayList.get(i));



    if (j>35 )
    {
        j=0;
    } 
    j++;

    }







}

}
```

I am getting an error in the line `E[j].setDate(arrayList.get(i));` It says that the actual argument cannot be converted to `java.lang.String` by method invocation.

All the fields in the object are `String` Types. The arrayList contains all the data extracted from the TXT file. I am trying to transfer all the data from the arrayList to the object array. The txt file has 35 columns and 1500 rows. The data being seperated by whitespace

Comment: I have one question , in the ArrayList i have diff datatypes and not just string ,I have int , float , double , then what do I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
ArrayList arrayList = null;
...
arrayList =new ArrayList();
```

to:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = null;
arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or just:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I have one question , in the ArrayList i have diff datatypes and not just string ,I have int , float , double , then what do I do ?

Comment: Use a separate list to store the different types: `ArrayList<Integer>`, `ArrayList<Double>`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A List contains Object instances. The get() method returns Object. If you want a typesafe List, you must use the generic type information:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you use the raw type (without the `<String>` generic type information), then the compiler doesn't know that the List only contains String instances, and you thus have to cast the result:

```
String s = (String) list.get(i);
```

Side note: learn to indent your code and to respect Java naming conventions. It's unreadable as is.

Comment: I have one question , in the ArrayList i have diff datatypes and not just string ,I have int , float , double , then what do I do ?

Comment: You redesign your program, because it's really not normal to have several kinds of data in a single list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're using the raw `ArrayList` type rather than using a parameterized `ArrayList`.  Consequently, all operations on the `ArrayList` will assume that the parameter and returns types are `Object` rather than `String`, since you haven't indicated to Java that you want the `ArrayList` to hold `String`s.  Without this extra information from you, Java can't know that the objects stored within are exclusively `String`s and not, say, `Integer`s, other `ArrayList`s, `JPanel`s, etc.

To fix this, change the line

```
private static ArrayList arrayList;
```

to read

```
private static ArrayList<String> arrayList;
```

This explicitly indicates to Java that your `ArrayList` should only hold `String`s, so it can know that the return type of `arrayList.get(i)` is going to be a `String` rather than the catch-all `Object`.  Similarly, change

```
arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For more information, read up on Java Generics.  They're a very powerful tool, but can easily be used improperly (as in your case).  One nice source is [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) by Oracle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have one question , in the ArrayList i have diff datatypes and not just string ,I have int , float , double , then what do I do ?

Comment: If you do have multiple data types, then you have two options.  First, you can use an `ArrayList<Object>` and treat everything uniformly as `Object`s.  Alternatively, you could use an `ArrayList<Object>`, then use type casts to convert the objects back to their real type once you know what that type is.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList= null;
```

ArrayList get call returns an Object unless you specify the type.

Comment: I have one question , in the ArrayList i have diff datatypes and not just string ,I have int , float , double , then what do I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Diamond was added in Java 7 :

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I have one question , in the ArrayList i have diff datatypes and not just string ,I have int , float , double , then what do I do ?